# Protect API Routes with Sanctum

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js

Is there any way to secure (access from outside the application) an api route using Sanctum without needing to email and password.

Comment: What do you mean "without needing to login"?

Comment: without email and password to access the specific protected route.

Comment: Sanctum was designed that way. You do not enter email and password, but token.

Comment: yes, but anyway I have to authenticate myself with email and password before generating the token, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use API tokens. You still need at least one user assigned, then you can assign a token and only send the token in the HttpRequest.

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication

Comment: You know where there is a tutorial, because the documentation is very confusing.

Comment: This one is pretty good.  It's long but worth it. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MT-GJQIY3EU&t=2028s